# Loading data from a staging table into a table with am auto-generated primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

I create an SQL table as shown below:

```
-- Create table
create table ASSET
(
  asset_id       NUMBER(12) default "MAS"."ASSET_SEQ"."NEXTVAL" not null,
  name           VARCHAR2(150 CHAR) not null,
  class          VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) not null,
  bucket         VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) not null,
  currency       VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) not null,
  quantity       NUMBER(12) not null,
  value          FLOAT not null,
  valuation_date DATE not null,
  expiry_date    DATE,
  fund_type      VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  bond_type      VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  isin           VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  underlying_id  NUMBER(12)
)
tablespace MAS_DATA
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
alter table ASSET
  add constraint PK_ASSET primary key (ASSET_ID)
  using index 
  tablespace MAS_DATA
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
alter table ASSET
  add constraint FK_UNDERLYING foreign key (UNDERLYING_ID)
  references UNDERLYING (UNDERLYING_ID);
```

My `STAGING` table contains the same attributes as the `ASSET` table above, except it does not have `ASSET_ID` (the PK of the `ASSET` table), or `UNDERLYING_ID` (a FK).

The sequence for the autogenerated `asset_id` is created with

```
-- Create sequence 
create sequence ASSET_SEQ
minvalue 1
maxvalue 9999999999999999999999999999
start with 844621
increment by 1
cache 20;
```

When I try to insert the data from my `STAGING` table using

```
insert into ASSET (NAME, CLASS, BUCKET, CURRENCY, QUANTITY, VALUE, VALUATION_DATE, EXPIRY_DATE, SECTOR, ISIN, UNDERLYING_ID)
       SELECT NAME, CLASS, BUCKET, CURRENCY, QUANTITY, VALUE, VALUATION_DATE, EXPIRY_DATE, SECTOR, ISIN, 0 FROM STAGING
```

The error: `ora-01400 cannot insert null into MAS.ASSET.NAME`

I think the issue is something related to `asset_id` not being defined as part of the values when inserting the values from `STAGING`, yet that value does not exist in `STAGING`, so it can't be selected from that table. Not sure where to go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused.  What part of the error do you not understand?  Clearly, a row in `staging` has a `NULL` name -- and that is not allowed.  I mean, there is the much less likely possibility that a trigger is causing the error, but the first possibility is much more likely.

You can get the offending records using:

```
select s.*
from staging s
where s.name is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error: ora-01400 cannot insert null into MAS.ASSET.NAME

It means the issue is that the STAGING table is containing empty records without a value for column "NAME" or that the ASSET table definition should be changed to allow null values for the column "NAME".
On the first case you can let the incomplete records behind by using the following

```
insert into ASSET (NAME, CLASS, BUCKET, CURRENCY, QUANTITY, VALUE, VALUATION_DATE, EXPIRY_DATE, SECTOR, ISIN, UNDERLYING_ID)
       SELECT NAME, CLASS, BUCKET, CURRENCY, QUANTITY, VALUE, VALUATION_DATE, EXPIRY_DATE, SECTOR, ISIN, 0 FROM STAGING WHERE NAME IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below statement to generate the sequence while inserting,

```
insert into ASSET ( asset_id,  NAME, CLASS, BUCKET, CURRENCY, QUANTITY, VALUE, 
VALUATION_DATE, EXPIRY_DATE, SECTOR, ISIN, UNDERLYING_ID)
   SELECT ASSET_SEQ.nextval, NAME, CLASS, BUCKET, CURRENCY, QUANTITY, VALUE, 
VALUATION_DATE, EXPIRY_DATE, SECTOR, ISIN, 0 FROM STAGING
```